# Post hoc tests: correct for all possible comparisons, or only those conducted?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

When conducting a post hoc test e.g. after an ANOVA and correcting for multiple comparisons, do I need to correct for all possible tests or only those that I am interested in? I've seen contradictory information on this. But I think that if I correct only for a few comparisons then that would essentially be a planned contrast, and since in a post hoc test I've already looked at all the different means (even if I only formally compared some of them) I do need to correct for all possible comparisons. Would be happy to hear comments on this or a source discussing the question since I could not find any.